# How to get file content from the IResource interface of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am using this function to get all the .class files of a selected project but I would like to get the contents of these files using the IFile interface getContents () but this method does not exist in IResource.

How can I get the contents of the files I get with the IResource of this function?

```
void processContainer(IContainer container) throws CoreException {
       IResource [] members = container.members();

       for (IResource member : members) {
          if (member instanceof IContainer)  {
             processContainer((IContainer)member);
           } else if (member instanceof IFile && member.isDerived()) {
              System.out.println(member);
           }
        } 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `getContents` on `IFile` so you will have to cast the `IResource` to `IFile`:

```
if (member instanceof IFile) {
   IFile file = (IFile)member;

   InputStream contents = file.getContents();

   ....
}
```

If the file is a text file read it with the correct encoding using:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getContents(), file.getCharset());
```